# How to update from a value obtained in a CTE ? - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to update data in a table based on the values of a CTE..I am having several problems, currently SQL Server says it cannot find the column name WeightedRating and I dont really know why..or what is it talking about.

Currently what I am trying is to mix a MERGE keyword along the CTEs.

This is my full query :

```
DECLARE @COUNT_VALUE FLOAT  -- MINIMUM OF VOTES REQUIRED TO BE LISTED IN THE TOP
DECLARE @minimumVotesRequired FLOAT  -- MINIMUM OF VOTES REQUIRED TO BE LISTED IN THE TOP
SET @minimumVotesRequired = 3

;WITH CTE_2 (SumOfVoteScore,CountOfVotes,IdProduct)
AS
(
SELECT
        SUM(r.Stars) AS SumOfVoteScore, -- THIS IS THE SUMMATORY OF ALL THE STARS THAT WERE GIVEN TO THE PRODUCT
        COUNT(rap.IdProduct) AS CountOfVotes, --HOW MANY RATINGS OF PRODUCTS WHERE MADE, this is the vote count
        rap.IdProduct
    FROM
        glamstapp.Rating AS r INNER JOIN glamstapp.RatingAndProducts AS rap ON r.IdRating = rap.IdRating

    GROUP BY
        rap.IdProduct

)
,CTE_3 (idProduct,vote_count,vote_mean1,vote_mean2)
AS
(
        SELECT  CONVERT(FLOAT,rap.IdProduct) as IdProduct,
               --ISNULL(CTE_2.SumOfVoteScore,0) AS vote_sum,
               CONVERT(FLOAT,CTE_2.CountOfVotes) AS vote_count,
               COALESCE((CONVERT(FLOAT,CTE_2.SumOfVoteScore)/  (CONVERT(FLOAT,CTE_2.CountOfVotes))),0) AS vote_mean1, --THE MEAN OF EACH PRODUCT
               COALESCE((CONVERT(FLOAT,CTE_2.SumOfVoteScore)/  (CONVERT(FLOAT,CTE_2.CountOfVotes))),0) AS vote_mean2
        FROM glamstapp.RatingAndProducts AS rap INNER JOIN  CTE_2 ON rap.idProduct = CTE_2.idProduct  
        GROUP BY rap.IdProduct,
                 CTE_2.SumOfVoteScore,
                 CTE_2.CountOfVotes
)
MERGE INTO glamstapp.RatingAndProducts
USING
(
SELECT CTE_3.idProduct,(CONVERT(FLOAT,CTE_3.vote_count) / (CONVERT(FLOAT,CTE_3.vote_count) + @minimumVotesRequired))
                        * CONVERT(FLOAT,CTE_3.vote_mean1) + 
                        (@minimumVotesRequired / (CONVERT(FLOAT,CTE_3.vote_count)+ @minimumVotesRequired))
                        * (SUM(CONVERT(FLOAT,CTE_3.vote_mean2))/(select count (CTE_3.vote_mean2) from CTE_3)) AS WeightedRating
FROM CTE_3 
GROUP BY
         CTE_3.vote_count,
         CTE_3.IdProduct,    
         CTE_3.vote_mean1   
)
AS Source
ON glamstapp.RatingAndProducts.idProduct = source.idProduct
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET glamstapp.RatingAndProducts.WeightedRating =  //<--The error is present in here or so SQL Server points out when I double click on the error.
source.WeightedRating ;;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `glamstapp.RatingAndProducts.WeightedRating` to just `WeightedRating`. You don't need to qualify the name by the database name or table, as the merge statement can only affect a single, already unambiguously stated table, and in fact, I believe even two to four part names I believe are prohibited in UPDATE and MERGE statements. See [MERGE (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) for the syntax, the relevant parts are:

```
[ WITH <common_table_expression> [,...n] ]
MERGE 
    [ TOP ( expression ) [ PERCENT ] ] 
    [ INTO ] <target_table> [ WITH ( <merge_hint> ) ] [ [ AS ] table_alias ]
    USING <table_source> 
    ON <merge_search_condition>
    [ WHEN MATCHED [ AND <clause_search_condition> ]
        THEN <merge_matched> ] [ ...n ]
    [ WHEN NOT MATCHED [ BY TARGET ] [ AND <clause_search_condition> ]
        THEN <merge_not_matched> ]
    [ WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE [ AND <clause_search_condition> ]
        THEN <merge_matched> ] [ ...n ]
    [ <output_clause> ]
    [ OPTION ( <query_hint> [ ,...n ] ) ]    
;
```

So what is the definition of `<merge_matched>`?

```
<merge_matched>::=
    { UPDATE SET <set_clause> | DELETE }
```

Okay, so what is a `<set_clause>`?

```
<set_clause>::=
SET
  { column_name = { expression | DEFAULT | NULL }
  | { udt_column_name.{ { property_name = expression
                        | field_name = expression }
                        | method_name ( argument [ ,...n ] ) }
    }
  | column_name { .WRITE ( expression , @Offset , @Length ) }
  | @variable = expression
  | @variable = column = expression
  | column_name { += | -= | *= | /= | %= | &= | ^= | |= } expression
  | @variable { += | -= | *= | /= | %= | &= | ^= | |= } expression
  | @variable = column { += | -= | *= | /= | %= | &= | ^= | |= } expression
  } [ ,...n ]
```

The important thing to note is that the syntax structure uses `column_name` and not `<column_name>`, where the latter may be specified with a multi-part name:

```
<column_name> ::=
    { DELETED | INSERTED | from_table_name } . { * | column_name }
    | $action
```

Again, the summary and key here is that when using a `MERGE` statement, the target table is already unambiguously specified, and so you do not need to use multi-part names on the left hand side of a SET expression, and the syntax actually prohibits that because there is *only* one valid table name, one valid database name, one valid server name for the left hand side of each part of the SET expression.